# Sum rows until customer number changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I sum the rows of product sales 1-3, until the Customer Code changes? Then the next Customer sales should be summed up. There may be customers with only 1 or 2 products also.

[image]

Comment: `SUMIF()` may work?

Comment: Get a unique list of either customer codes or customer names (whichever can be trusted) then use sumifs().

Comment: This would be a whole lot easier using a Pivot Table I think

Answer (score 3):

If you have CustomerId in column A and Sales in column B, you could add an extra column C with formula:

```
=IF(A2=A1,C1+B2,B2)
```

And then drag it down.

[image: Excel picture]

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the reason why the subtotals feature has been invented. Hereby a screenshot (not in English, sorry):

[image]

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a) is the URL of the official documentation.